# How to specify python regular expression that starts with "testing" without declaring the content variable?

Tags: python

I have written following python code, to uninstall "testing_kip-win32" software in windows.

```
import wmi
import re

 c = wmi.WMI()

print ("Searching for matching products...")
for product in c.Win32_Product(Name = "testing_kip-win32"):
  print ("Uninstalling" + product.Name + "...")
  result = product.Uninstall()
```

But in the above code, instead of giving full name "testing_kip-win32", I want to give a software name that startswith "testing". Then this script should uninstall "testing_kip-win32".

Any ideas please?

Thanks in advance

NOTE : I am using python 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the regular expression module `re`, the code you need will look something like:

```
import re

m = re.match("^testing", "ptesting_kip-win332")
if m != None:
     print ("Uninstalling" + product.Name + "...")
     result = product.Uninstall()
```

You could also consider to use the string function `startswith()`
which will work something like:

```
name = "testing_kip-win332"

if name.startswith("testing"):
    print ("Uninstalling" + product.Name + "...")
    result = product.Uninstall()
```